# FAIL - Application already exists at path and FAIL - Unable to delete

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, web-applications, apache-tomee

I searched for this error, but I was not able to solve it with the given answers. I am using Netbeans and Mysql database and Tomcat server. If I close Netbeans, delete the file, and try to run it again, it works, but I do not want to do that every time.

```
    ---------------------------< 1:ExpLearnApp >----------------------------
Building ExpLearnApp 1
--------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------

--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:copy (default) @ ExpLearnApp ---
The artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2 has been relocated to xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ExpLearnApp ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 2 resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ ExpLearnApp ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ ExpLearnApp ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\kllj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ExpLearnApp\src\test\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ExpLearnApp ---
No sources to compile

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ ExpLearnApp ---

--- maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) @ ExpLearnApp ---
Packaging webapp
Assembling webapp [ExpLearnApp] in [C:\Users\kllj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ExpLearnApp\target\ExpLearnApp-1]
Processing war project
Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\kllj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ExpLearnApp\src\main\webapp]
Webapp assembled in [138 msecs]
Building war: C:\Users\kllj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ExpLearnApp\target\ExpLearnApp-1.war
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  1.677 s
Finished at: 2022-09-09T16:08:07-05:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Deploying on Apache Tomcat or TomEE (1)
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Undeploying ...
undeploy?path=/ExpLearnApp
FAIL - Unable to delete [C:\Users\kllj\Downloads\apache-tomee-1.7.5-webprofile\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.5\conf\Catalina\localhost\ExpLearnApp.xml]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.
In-place deployment at C:\Users\kllj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ExpLearnApp\target\ExpLearnApp-1
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fkrollj%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext7669747224496347498.xml&path=/ExpLearnApp
FAIL - Application already exists at path /ExpLearnApp
```

Comment: You could try with [maven-war-plugin:exploded](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/exploded-mojo.html) if available.

Comment: I tried but id did not work. Same error.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you have any chance to fix it?

Comment: I did not find a solution. I created another project, moved the file and it worked.